# How to get the Character by Point or by index from TRichedit

Tags: delphi, char, position, message, richedit

I have function that returns the index of a character GetCharFromPos(Pt: TPoint): Integer;

now i wanted to get character of that position. like GetCharByIndex(Index: Integer): Char;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The efficient way to do this using pure VCL is to use `SelStart`, `SelLength` and `SelText`.

```
function GetCharByIndex(Index: Integer): Char;
begin    
  RichEdit.SelStart := Index;
  RichEdit.SelLength := 1;
  Result := RichEdit.SelText[1];
end;
```

You'll likely want to save away the selection before modifying it, and then restore it once you have read the character.

---

This is however a rather messy way to read a character.  If you are prepared to use raw Win32 API then you can make use of [`EM_GETTEXTRANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774199%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you return the character at a given index from a TRichEdit:

```
Result := RichEdit1.Text[Index];
```

Comment: this is extraordinarily inefficient since it reads the entire text in order to pick out a single character.